# Help in understanding a unclear notation in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I'm trying to understand the paper "On the number of maximal sum-free sets" by T. Luczak and T. Schoen but unfortunately, I don't quite understand the notation (my fault, for sure).

The text says:

[image]

Say $A$={1,3,5} with $n=6$, and $B$={1,3}. What is the meaning of $(A\setminus B)/2$?

I assume the $/2$ applies only to $(A\setminus B)$ and not to the whole union as $(A\setminus B)$ has already been added to it. I thought maybe it meant quotient set, but $2$ is not a set.

I understand $(A\setminus B)/2$ is {5}$/2$ (in my example) but I have no idea what that means.

Many thanks

Comment: Possibly it's the image of the map $x\mapsto x/2$, i.e: dividing by two every element in the set. Would this make sense?

Comment: While I don't think that it is intended here, the standard set-theoretic interpretation of the natural numbers is $0=\emptyset$, $s(n)=n\cup\{n\}$, so $/2$ *could* mean the quotient set $/\{0,1\}$. However, I would guess that $/2$ is meant in the same sense as $(A\setminus B)+(A\setminus B)$. I've seen "$+$" used for union before, but since we have "$\cup$" as well, it must mean something else. If $(A\setminus B)+(A\setminus B)$ is meant to indicate $\{x+y:x,y\in A\setminus B\}$, then I would guess that $(A\setminus B)/2=\{x/2:x\in A\setminus B\}$.

Comment: Just keep reading into the proof of Lemma 3.

Comment: The vertical bars suggest that $h_A(B)$ is the cardinality of a set, and that the $/2$ where it appears is a misplacement typo. It belongs at the end. Context will tell.

Comment: @EthanBolker: As the expression also contains "$+$" and "$-$" used on sets (and "$\cup$" and "$\setminus$" so it's not just non-standard notation for those operations), I don't think that's the answer.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Nor do I. Just a suggestion. Without more context from the OP there's no way to know.